# Can i5-2410M@2.30GHz 2.30GHz cpu support 64-bit OS?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

My model have  I5-2410M@2.30GHz 2.30GHz processor , 3 GB RAM , 640 GB Hard Disk. I want to upgrade it from 32-bit Windows-enterprise to 64-bit Windows Ultimate. Can I do it?  Will it support?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the [i5-2410M](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Core-i5-2410M-Notebook-Processor.45317.0.html) is 64 bit capable.  You will be able to install Windows Ultimate 64 bit, but an [upgrade](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions) is not possible.

Comment: It's a complete structure change. It's not like upgrading from say Windows Vista to Windows 7. 64 bit also makes the most use from machines with 4GB + of RAM. You may want to upgrade that as well to get the full benefit.